# Адаптер для работы с БД

Tags: ооп, php, mysql

Это метод класса для работы с базой данных. Вопрос для чего нужна конструкция 
($key . '') ?

```
    public function Insert($table, $object)
{           
    $columns = array();
    $values = array();

    foreach ($object as $key => $value)
    {
        $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key . '');
        $columns[] = $key;

        if ($value === null)
        {
            $values[] = 'NULL';
        }
        else
        {
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value . '');                         
            $values[] = "'$value'";
        }
    }

    $columns_s = implode(',', $columns);
    $values_s = implode(',', $values);

    $query = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns_s) VALUES ($values_s)";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result)
        die(mysql_error());

    return mysql_insert_id();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, `$key . ''` - просто преобразование типа переменной к строке. Для чего это нужно в конкретном случае - непонятно: PHP сам умеет преобразовывать типы. Видимо, для наглядности.

Answer (score 0):

```
string mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier ] )
```

Экранирует специальные символы в unescaped_string, принимая во внимание кодировку соединения, таким образом, что результат можно безопасно использовать в SQL-запросе в функци mysql_query(). Если вставляются бинарные данные, то к ним так же необходимо применять эту функцию.

mysql_real_escape_string() вызывает библиотечную функцмю MySQL mysql_real_escape_string, которая добавляет обратную косую черту к следующим символам: x00, n, r, , ', " and x1a.

Эта функция должна всегда (за несколькими исключениями) использоваться для того, чтобы обезопасить данные, вставляемые в запрос перед отправкой его в MySQL.

хотя бы иногда юзайте гугл

Comment: Спасибо, что это за функция я знаю. Вопрос был для чего нужна конструкция ($key . ''), а точнее одинарные кавычки.

Comment: Глаза раскройте. Написано же в аргументах, что нужна строка.

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: А вопрос не судьба прочитать? Мне не нужно описание функции.